# Clear a observable array angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

How do I remove all the items from the observable array? It is part of an infinity scroll

https://stackblitz.com/edit/infinite-scroll-firestore?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

```
 this.data = this._data.asObservable()
  .pipe(
    scan( (acc, val) => { 
      return this.query.prepend ? val.concat(acc) : acc.concat(val)
    })
  )
```

i want to remove everything in the data array.
the reset functions didn't do anything to the data observable
it just removes from the _data

```
reset() {
  this._data.next([])
}
```

I also tried setting it to null but it didn't work

```
reset() {
  this._data.next(null)
}
```

Even if I set it like this

```
this.data = new Observable
```

Comment: I noticed from your code that `reset()` function is not called.

Comment: i did call it i just didn't  add it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply several higher order functions to mutate the state:

```
const reset = () => (state) => [];
const add = (newValue) => (state) => [...state, newValue];
const overwrite = (newState) => (state) => newState;

const reset$ = new Subject();
const add$ = new Subject();
const data$ = this._data.asObservable()
...

const data = merge(
  reset$.pipe(map(reset)),
  add$.pipe(map(add)),
  data$.pipe(map(overwrite))
).pipe(
  scan((state, fn) => fn(state), [])
);
```

- Nexting the `reset$` will clear your state: `reset$.next();`
- Nexting a value to the `add$` will add the value to your state: `add$.next(1);`
- If your `_data` emits a new value it will overwrite the current state

Comment: and what is _data? not show in code.

Comment: `this._data.asObservable()` is an Observable that the original questions contains. It can be whatever `Observable` or `Subject` you want to use. As I answered a specific question here, I referred to it. If you want you can also write `const data$ = new Subject()` or `const data$ = this.myOwnObservable$`.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will assign empty observable array to the data object

```
this.data = of([]);
```

Comment: @GuerricP The question is about to reset the observable array, right?

Comment: You don't clear the old subscriptions -> cause potential memory leaks. Also if the consumer does not subscribe new he wont get the value. You should work with the current state (scan) he built up and don't overwrite the old observable.